# Gcov Coverage: Can we do coverage for just a few lines of code in a File.

Tags: c++, code-coverage, gcov

I need to generate a report with coverage for just the new lines of code added with in each sprint. Other than using comments is there a way to do that using the gcov/lcov tool.

Comment: [OpenCppCoverage](https://github.com/OpenCppCoverage/OpenCppCoverage/wiki/Command-line-reference#--unified_diff--unifieddiffpath--rootfolder-) (for windows) has that option.